# Error in aspx page when “src” is used

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Net project in Visual Studio 2005. It has a subfolder called ASPX inside which there are many aspx pages.  This is an existing project and when I run the website, I get the following error –

> Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of 'ASP.aspx_anetnews_aspx'.
>
> Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" src="anetNews.aspx.vb" CodeBehind="anetNews.aspx.vb" Inherits="MyNamespace.anetNews" %>

When I remove the src="anetNews.aspx.vb" part, it is working fine. This is the scenario for all page (almost 100 pages) in the website. I guess this is some setting issue in project properties. Any guess what could be this setting issue?

**Note**: I guess this project was migrated to VS2005 from .Net 1.0, without any code/solution change.

**Note**: I downloaded the source code from VSS and set it up in my machine.

**Note**: I have referred [Aspx page doesn't compile when page is copied from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311071/aspx-page-doesnt-compile-when-page-is-copied-from-another-project). If I conver the project as a web application, this issue goes away. But I am not allowd to make this change. There is some other setting that I am missing

**REFERENCES**:

1. [social.msdn - BC30456: 'InitializeCulture' is not a member of ....](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/54a40a36-209a-46ee-b834-df946532719f/bc30456-initializeculture-is-not-a-member-of-fixes)
2. [Aspx page doesn't compile when page is copied from another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2311071/aspx-page-doesnt-compile-when-page-is-copied-from-another-project)

Comment: AFAIK you don't need a src attribute, only CodeBehind ?

Comment: @sh1rts This is an existing project started development somewhere in 2003 or so.. It is working copy. So, instead of removing "src" from all files, I am looking for a solution

Comment: have you try to remove `CodeBehind` and work with only `src`?

Answer (score 1):

You failed to mention it was from a previous version of Visual Studio, but never mind. The src attribute is deprecated beyond .NET 2.0, and the recommended approach is to use Inherits/CodeFile instead. I don't know why you're getting a runtime error, but your solution IS to remove the src attribute from each page.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ydy4x04a%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**Src**

Specifies a path to a source file containing code that is linked to the page. In the linked source file, you can choose to include programming logic for your page either in a class or in code declaration blocks.

You can use the Src attribute to link build providers to the page. For more information, see the BuildProvider class. Also, in versions of ASP.NET prior to 2.0, the Src attribute was used as an alternative way to link a code-behind file to a page. In ASP.NET 2.0, the preferred approach to linking a code-behind source file to a page is to use the Inherits attribute to specify a class, along with the CodeFile attribute to specify the path to the source file for the class.

Comment: Thanks.  But I cannot delete src / code behind from all the 100 pages

Comment: You can't just open each file and remove the "src='blablabla'" attribute ? Why not ? I know it's a bit manual labour, but ..